# FloatingActionButton Sub can't call another form in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

I have multiple forms and in one of the forms, I want to navigate to another form using `FloatingActionButton` `createSubFab`. Whenever I click the `subFab` button, it always re-display it's parent form (Briefly shows the other form and back to its parent form... if you blink, you will miss it).

I have tried this on 2 different Apps and the end results were the same. Here is the code I'm using:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CREATE); 
fab.bindFabToContainer(getContentPane()); 
fab.createSubFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_CREATE, "Write on public forum").addActionListener(evt -> {
    setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createCover(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, false, 200));     
    new ForumNewPostForm(f, "Public").show(); 
});
```

Could this be a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Shai in an email, this is caused by a minor bug on Codename One which has been resolved and will be available on next update.